# Getting Model has not been initialized. Please buildModel first for a retrofit api call

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, retrofit2

I am making a retrofit call in this way:-

```
 
           
                APIInterface apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);
                
                AppLogger.getInstance().e("TAG", "Request visit: " +obj1);
                Call<ResponseBody> call1=apimethod(obj1);
                call1.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                        AppLogger.getInstance().e("TAG", "Response add " + response.body()
 }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                        AppLogger.getInstance().e("Tag", "Response add " +t);
                    }
                });
```

and my API Call is like:-

```
@POST("route for the route")
    Call<ResponseBody> apimethod(@Body Class1 obj);
```

and I am initializing retrofit object in this way:-

```
public static Retrofit getClient() {
        HttpsTrustManager.allowAllSSL();
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
        client=getUnsafeOkHttpClient().build();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("<apiurl>")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(getUnsafeOkHttpClient().build())
                .build();



        return retrofit;
    }
```

But while submitting the response:-
Req body is correct as per the api body

```
{Object }
```

and the final response is like which is very weird:-

```
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: {"timestamp":"2020-06-28T12:28:20.410+0000","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Model has not been initialized. Please buildModel first","path":"<route for it>"}
```

Here all details are getting initialised but unable to get why this is saying Model is not intialised

Comment: As far as I understand, this answer comes from the service you requested. other operations need to be done before this request can be fulfilled. I guess the path value returned in the answer is the router of that service...

Comment: Did not get what u told.Is it like getting the text from the ui before creating a object.If that is the case I am getting the request object correctly